# JS missing formal parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

Within a website I need to switch panels during the load of a page based on a parameter set in code behind, and needs to be switched through javascript. The parameter is being included within the javascript function in code-behind but I am receiving an error of 'missing formal parameter', what may be the problem?

Here is the code that is generated by the RegisterClientScriptBlock:

```
<script language='javascript'>function switchactionpanel(1)</script>
```

Here is the code-behind that registers the script to call on load:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String switchAction = "<script language='javascript'>function switchactionpanel(" + (int)((Global.upAction) Enum.Parse(typeof(Global.upAction), Global.ProfileAction.ToString())) + ")</script>";
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("switchaction", switchAction);
}
```

Here is the javascript function within the aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function switchactionpanel(upaction) {
        switch (upaction) {
            case 1:
                $('#urfcontainer').hide();
                $('#rstcontainer').show();
                break;
            case 2:
                $('#urfcontainer').show();
                $('#rstcontainer').hide();
                break;
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the generated javascript is wrong. You have a 'function' keyword too much. You get:

```
 <script language='javascript'>function switchactionpanel(1)</script>
```

which doesn't make sense. Just make sure you get

```
 <script language='javascript'>switchactionpanel(1)</script>
```

and you should be fine. Remove the 'function' keyword here:

```
String switchAction = "<script language='javascript'>function switchactionpanel(" + (int)((Global.upAction) Enum.Parse(typeof(Global.upAction), Global.ProfileAction.ToString())) + ")</script>";
```

Comment: awesome thank you, kinda embarassing that I forget those little things sometimes